# imap_delete versus mails with .xls attachments

Tags: php, imap

We have a PHP script that opens a mailbox with `imap_open`, checks it for new messages, posts them onto our intranet, and then `imap_delete`s the message and `imap_expunge`s the mailbox.

Generally this works okay, but sometimes the script fails to evict the message from the mailbox.  This usually seems to be when the mail has a `.xls` attachment, though there exists the possibility that that's a red herring.

I've tried reworking things several times to get this to work properly, but without any success.  Most of the time `imap_delete` does exactly what we want it to.  Is there any obvious reason why [`imap_delete`](http://php.net/imap_delete) / [`expunge`](http://php.net/imap_expunge) would fail to delete from a mailbox?

Or can anyone suggest a better way of deleting a mail that is being "difficult"?

ETA:

```
$check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($mailbox);
echo "Messages before delete: " . $check->Nmsgs . "<br />\n";

imap_delete($mailbox, $i);

$check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($mailbox);
echo "Messages after delete: " . $check->Nmsgs . "<br />\n";

imap_expunge($mailbox);

$check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($mailbox);
echo "Messages after expunge: " . $check->Nmsgs . "<br />\n";
```

Results in:

```
Messages before delete: 1
Messages after delete: 1
Messages after expunge: 1
```

Both imap_delete and imap_expunge are giving a return value of true.  imap_errors() is empty at all points during and after the process. Nothing looks out of the ordinary in the access log.

imap_fetch_overview after the imap_delete call does indicate that the delete flag has been correctly set.  The imap_fetch_overview call after imap_expunge() returns just the same thing, delete flag still set.  So I guess the expunge seems to be not expunging, in the case of certain mails... The results of imap_fetch_overview both times:

> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#16 (14) { ["subject"]=> string(23)
>   "(Subject)" ["from"]=> string(40) "(Sender)"
>   ["to"]=> string(24) "undisclosed-recipients: " ["date"]=> string(31)
>   "Sun, 30 Dec 2012 23:36:34 +0000" ["message_id"]=> string(50) ""
>   ["size"]=> int(89752) ["uid"]=> int(1) ["msgno"]=> int(1) ["recent"]=>
>   int(1) ["flagged"]=> int(0) ["answered"]=> int(0) ["deleted"]=> int(1)
>   ["seen"]=> int(1) ["draft"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: It's a Mac Mini running Apache.

Comment: No, I mean what kind of a server is the IMAP box running on? Exchange?

Comment: @Pekka, oh, sorry.  I passed that question "upstairs" and was told "unsure, but it's on Dreamhost".  That may not be very useful I guess!  I could try and do some more research.

Comment: If you want more activity on your question here, improve the question and place for example a bounty. But please do not duplicate [delref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122362/any-workaround-for-imap-delete?lq=1) - To improve your question please for example give a listing of the flags before deletition / expunge of the message you can not delete and afterwards. Also give a small code-example and document return values.

Comment: @hakre: Sorry for the protocol breach, born of sheer frustration at my inability to find meaningful-looking information to provide, I assure you.  I guess declaring the problem unsolvable in a fit of pique is not the answer.

Comment: @thesunneversets: Yes, I had thought so, hence I did not downvote. Consider placing a bounty. Also both `imap_delete` and `imap_expunge` have a return value. Check that and add it's output to your question (use `var_dump` for booleans so it it's more clear).

Comment: @hakre Both imap_delete and imap_expunge are returning true - I'll add that above!

Comment: Okay so the server reports that the file was deleted and expunge operation succeeded. Can you check that after the *delete* operation the file is marked for deletion/expunge? - Ignore, seeing you already check there - hey but not the flags. Do not only display the count but also which flags those messages (in your case that one) have (has).

Comment: @hakre I was worried you were going to press me about examining the flags, it seems a bit tricky to do! I'm trying to modify the code found in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285690/how-to-get-imap-flags but it's not working for me at all so far :-/

Comment: No not that buggy one, just check http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetch-overview.php look if ***deleted*** entry is set or not - or even simpler, just `print_r` the whole array for debugging.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22065/discussion-between-thesunneversets-and-hakre)

Answer (score 0):

There might be some condition on the server side that causes this. Log the result from imap_errors() to see if the delete fails. It should also be pretty straight forward to see if an Excel attachment is the cause, and if a particular file / file format is to blame. Perhaps the post is refused at the intranet and therefor never deleted?

Comment: Pretty sure that the post isn't being refused at the intranet... as the main symptom of the problem is the post being reposted dozens of time on the intranet!  I should have mentioned that earlier.  I'll have a go with imap_errors() and see if that provides any useful output.

Comment: Hmph, the problem has (finally) recurred and my log of imap_errors() doesn't seem to show anything unusual.  Maybe I can deduce from that it's not a problem with imap!  I would like to think some kind of error would arise if imap_delete tries to delete something but doesn't succeed.  I guess I should double-check that the imap_delete is being called at all...

Comment: Yep, imap_delete is called, imap_errors has nothing in it, but the message remains undeleted and in the inbox. Baffled!