# What is the best way to mark parsed emails as "parsed" .. just delete them?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm writing an email parser for a site and I'm not sure of best practices.  Specifically, I am not sure how to mark emails that I have already parsed, so I don't access them each time I access the mailbox.

PS - I've never done *any* email parsing.

I'm using the Flourish library (along with Codeigniter) so so far I am calling cronjobs/parseMail with a cron job

```
public function parseMail(){
    // Connect to a remote imap server
    $mailbox = new fMailbox('imap', 'mysite.com', 'user', 'password');

    // Retrieve an overview of all messages
    $messages = $mailbox->listMessages();

    foreach ( $messages as $message ){
        $messageBody = $message['text'];
        // parse it
    }
}
```

So once I have "dealt with" an email.. should I just delete it?  Or is there a better way to insure that I am not parsing emails I have already done?

BONUS QUESTION > Dont I need to supply a specific email account somewhere?  If I have "admin@mysite.com" and "addressForParsing@mysite.com" .. where does that get specified that I am only interested in the latter?  Do I just pull the "To:" out of my parsed info or is there a better way?

Comment: You could hash them and store them in a data store.

Answer (score 1):

1. Flourish: wow... this is even less helpful than the stock PHP functions. You'll have to store message UIDs externally from IMAP to track if something's been processed or not.
2. PHP/CodeIgniter: CI doesn't seem to have an IMAP library, so you're using PHP functions. [`imap-setflag-full()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-setflag-full.php) will let you set the `\Flagged` flag on the message which you can use to track if the message has been processed.
3. Custom Socket Code: you can use something like [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6994157/1064767) to set/get custom IMAP flags, but you'll probably have to read a handful of IMAP RFCs to get everything else working.

Comment: I think Flourish's strength is that listMessages gives you an array of  message UIDs with the value of each key being an array of the various message part.  It seemed useful, or at least the simplest library for accessing IMAP since CI has nothing.  Do you not like Flourish from experience or was the comment just based on what you saw here?

Comment: @K.K.Smith actually I looked up the Flourish docs on fMailbox. It's *simpler* than the built-in PHP functions to be sure, but it doesn't really add anything as far as I saw. PHP just has generally terrible IMAP support when you're looking at the more esoteric features like custom flags, and I've yet to see any Socket-based solution that does it any better. Really, if you've parsed the message and never plan to do anything else with it just delete the thing and make your email server admin happy.