# PHP imap_* functions and custom flags

Tags: php, imap

I'm currently playing with PHP's IMAP functions.

I'm trying to write and read messages and flags. But I encountered a small problem while fetching custom flags.

Exactly I mean `\\forwarded` flag.

According to what I found its part of IMAP4 specification. So I switched an `/imap4` flat while calling `imap_open`.

Also found this "bug": https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39440

So basically, is there any way to fetch custom flags using `imap_*` functions? (or at last any other way?)

`imap_fetch_overview` does not return this flag even if it's specified on message. So it only returns non-custom flags such as: seen, delted, answered, flagged and draft (+ recent).

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285690/how-to-get-imap-flags

Comment: Didn't find this answer. But I'm looking for approach that would allow me to use standard imap_* functions since my program is based on them.

Comment: So basically, if I get it right, you want to find emails by custom flag, which is not set by imap_setflag_*?

Comment: @Gacek you can overwrite (redefine) those functions by any class working with imap and supporting features you want.

Comment: I basically copy messages from one mailbox to other (on different servers). And am thinking of a way to preserve/move flags across.

Comment: @Gacek why do you want to use php for that? there is a nice `imapcopy` program for that.

Comment: Basically more for training purpouses and out of being courious :)